# EF Code-first, how to insert primary key to another field when inserting?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

This is my entity that I will insert into the database:

```
public sampleEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

`Ticket` is in the format like

```
string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}-{1}", DateTime.Now, PrimaryKey);
```

So when I add this entity to the context, `primaryKey` always is 0, so `Ticket` value always be '20170315-0'

For now my solution is

```
// first add row and save
SampleEntity sample = new SampleEntity {
    Ticket=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
};
context.Samples.Add(sample);
context.SaveChanges();

// then find it out and update
var latest = context.Samples.OrderByDecending(p => p.PrimaryKey).First();
latest.Ticket += sample.PrimaryKey.ToString();
context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I set `Ticket` value according to `primaryKey` value when `SaveChanges()` without update?

Comment: You basically need a trigger. If you want it to be entirely EF-based, you probably want something like [this project](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers).

Comment: How is the `primaryKey` value determined? Is this handled by the underlying database engine (which one)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` option for primary key.

That means that **only** SQL Server know that ID, and that knowledge materializes **only** in the moment of the actual `INSERT` into database (as related column in database is some kind of `IDENTITY` column).

To understand that think, for example, of two applications which are inserting new records into database simultaneously - they will receive different keys, but you cannot know for sure which application receive which key.

Entity Framework will generate two requests for `SaveChanges` - first one is `INSERT`, and another one is `SELECT` to receive that generated key.

Only after that your code will know actual key and can be able to use it for your ticket calculations - so basically you cannot avoid another `UPDATE` with EF.

What you can do though is to change Primary Key type for something controlled by your code rather than by database - for example, random GUID; in this case you will know ID *before* insert and can use it in any way you want.

But using say GUID for primary key results in other complications, which in most cases won't worth it, like non-sequential insert results in often index rebuilds, still some probability of keys collision, more space to keep column etc.

Another option would be to have *calculated* column OR similar logic for ticket column in application, so you will have separate Date column and separate Id column, but for ticket you will either always apply concat logic whenever you need it, of create calculated column which will only return values (and thus will be read-only for database and EF).